# Lifespan/storage of Bokashi Flakes (compost)

Tags: compost

I've made *bokashi* flakes from bran and LAB liquid, been using it for a while.

Dried the flakes and stored in plastic boxes, but I am unsure if that is the best way to
store, since I know the bacteria inside does not like oxygen, and clearly a box has oxygen.

It also made me wonder - How long *bokashi* flakes can last?

---

### Additional details:

Daytime time temperatures: summer **30-40c**, winter **4-15c**
Night time temperatures: summer **27-30c**, winter **3-9c**
Humidity: **~65-85%**

Bokashi flakes were made from home-made LAB liquid from rice water, fructose syrup & wheat bran mixed with water, inside garbage bags for some weeks and then sun-dried and stored in small boxes, placed in a closed shed.

Comment: Good question; if could include dimensions of the containers, typical daytime & night time temperatures, typical humidity, and percentages of the materials used to make the  compost, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!